# Java Script React problem with add property onclick to Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I plugin external script.js to index.html in react js project .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   ....
  </head>
  <body>
  <script id="zoom" src="./script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

and i try use function in this script in automatic generate object in react file:

```
const image = document.createElement("IMG");
 image.onclick="magnify(this, 3)";
 image.onmousemove="init(event)";
```

It's not work for me (i have error with type),but if add attribute in dev tool its work [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfgBg.png) . Im sure i add script with this information.

How add it's i my code ? 
sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

I see in your devtools the image is being rendered, is the problem that you cannot see it?

Try setting the width and height of the image:

```
image.style.cssText = "width: 100px; height: 100px"
```

Comment: I have problem with add event attribute to image. I cant add Onclick and onmousemove its use in zoom. It cant be a string like I do in project. I looking for answer i find information its must be function not string with name function but i dont can use function from another js file added in index.html